# Reading a web page with node.js and urllib

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, urllib

I'm learning programming and found myself in a tough spot; the code from the tutorial is not working and I can't understand why.
It's a shell script that's supposed to retrieve a wikipedia page, strip it of the references, and return just the paragraphs text.
It uses the urllib library. In the code below, the only difference from the tutorial's is the use of fs to make a text file with the page content. The rest is copied and pasted.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

// Returns the paragraphs from a Wikipedia link, stripped of reference numbers.

let urllib = require("urllib");
let url = process.argv[2];
let fs = require("fs");

console.log(url);

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

urllib.request(url, { followRedirect: true }, function(error, data, response) {
  let body = data.toString();
  // Simulate a Document Object Model.
  let { document } = (new JSDOM(body)).window;

  // Grab all the paragraphs and references.
  let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  let references = document.querySelectorAll(".reference");

  // Remove any references.
  references.forEach(function(reference) {
    reference.remove();
  });

  // Print out all of the paragraphs.
  paragraphs.forEach(function(paragraph) {
    console.log(paragraph.textContent);
    fs.appendFileSync("article.txt", `${paragraph}\n`);
  });

});
```

My first guess, was that urllib was not working for some reason. This cause, even if I installed it as per official [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urllib), when I type `which urllib` at the command line, it doesn't return a path.
But then, node doesn't return an error for not knowing what the `require("urllib")` is when I run the file.

The actual output is the following:

```
$ ./wikp https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript
$
```

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tutorial you followed might have been a little out of date.
This works for me:

```
let urllib = require("urllib");
let url = process.argv[2];
let fs = require("fs");

console.log(url);

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;


urllib.request(url, { followRedirect: true }).then(({data, res}) => {
  let body = data.toString();
  // Simulate a Document Object Model.
  let { document } = (new JSDOM(body)).window;

  // Grab all the paragraphs and references.
  let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  let references = document.querySelectorAll(".reference");

  // Remove any references.
  references.forEach(function(reference) {
    reference.remove();
  });

  // Print out all of the paragraphs.
  paragraphs.forEach(function(paragraph) {
    console.log(paragraph.textContent);
    fs.appendFileSync("article.txt", `${paragraph.textContent}\n`);
  });
});
```

The package you are using (urllib) is using promises, that might have been different in the past, when the tutorial was released.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. Did you get to this by reading the urllib documentation, or you just knew how to use it from experience? I'm just wondering, cause at the stage where I'm at in my learning, the documentation is quite difficult to understand for me

Comment: I have not used urllib before, but many other libraries. So experience from that helped a lot. 
First I tried your code and then saw that urllib.request was returning a promise. 
(by adding a temporary console.log(urllib.request))
Then I checked the docs you linked. As you can see in their example they are using it more like I did - without the callback but with an "await" - await is pretty much the same as my .then(()=>{}). If you have not heard about promises yet, you might want to check out a tutorial about them. They are js specific and very neat to use when you "really get them".

Comment: Never even heard of promises. I'll check it out. And thanks for the thorough explanation of the process you used to solve this. That's exactly the type of explanation I needed.